# I need a script to send email reminders for tasks that are due the next day

Tags: php

I have a script that allows site users to save tasks to the system using a jquery-ui date picker.  This due date is then stored in the database as a timestamp.  The timestamp is based on the users local timezone, per jquery-ui documentation.

I have a daily cron that runs a script that gets all the tasks from the database that haven't had reminders sent, and checks to see if the due date of each task is tomorrow, or in the past, and sends an email reminder to the owner that a task is coming up.

The problem I'm having is that some tasks are having reminders sent a day early, like instead of the task being due tomorrow, the task is actually due the day after tomorrow.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($this->tasks as $task) {
        // Get owner guid of task
        $owner_guid = $task->owner_guid;
        // Get owner entity of task
        $owner = getEntity($owner_guid);
        // Get owner timezone
        $owner_timezone = $owner->timezone;
        // If owner timezone not set, set it to default.
        if (!$owner_timezone) {
            $owner_timezone = "America/New_York";
        }
        // Get timestamp of task due date in users timzone
        $due_timestamp_user_timezone = $task->due_date;
        // Check if task has a due date.
        if ($due_timestamp_user_timezone) {
            // Convert server time to user timezone.
            $dt = new \DateTime();
            $dt->setTimestamp(time());
            $tz = new \DateTimeZone($owner_timezone);
            $dt->setTimeZone($tz);
            $server_today_timestamp = $dt->format('U');
            $server_today_date = date("Ymd", $server_today_timestamp);
            $dt->modify("+1 day");
            $server_tomorrow_timestamp = $dt->format('U');
            $server_tomorrow_date = date("Ymd", $server_tomorrow_timestamp);
            $task_due_date = date("Ymd", $due_timestamp_user_timezone);
            if (($server_tomorrow_date == $task_due_date) || ($server_today_date >= $task_due_date)) {
                // send reminder here
            }
```

Comment: you should be able to get all of your rows with in your MySQL query instead of what your doing in php

Comment: Thanks, cmorrissey, but $this->tasks is an array of objects that are pulled from the database.  I'm trying to figure out why the reminders are being sent a day early.